# datetimepicker disabled dates

Tags: jquery, date, format, datetimepicker

I'm trying to disable multiple random dates (closing dates of the company) on datetimepicker.

My code:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format:'dd M. yyyy - h:00 uur',
    language: 'nl',
    startDate: '+2d',
    weekStart: '1',
    daysOfWeekDisabled:'6,0',
    maxView: '2',
    minView:'1',
    disabledDates: ['2015-08-25', '2015-08-26']
});
```

Any help?

Comment: What's not working or what is happening? What datetimepicker plugin are you using (provide a link).

Comment: Have you tried putting the `disabledDates` values in the same format as `format`?

Comment: this is the one I'm using: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. I've also tried to add the disabledDates in the same format (example: "27 Aug. 2015 - 12:00 uur") but without effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the options you have set don't exist in this version of the plugin, and/or are set incorrectly. Hopefully this will get you started in the right direction. 
 http://jsfiddle.net/Ludz03xe/

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format:'LL LTS',
    locale: 'nl',
    defaultDate: moment().add(2,'days'),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    disabledDates: ['2015-08-25', '2015-08-26']
});
```

You may need to refer to moment formats to format your date as desired
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/